# Ajax options to validate and bind form information

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have forms in my application that are posted to a database and then displayed in datatables when they are submitted.

I am using Ajax.begin form to run my JS functions on them. However, I can only get the first function to run. I would like to be able to run both functions and post the information.

Here is the beginForm in my HTML:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddDiagnosis", "Student",
            new AjaxOptions(){              
                OnBegin = "return ValidateAddStudentDiagnosisCode(" + @studentId + ")",
                OnSuccess = "HandleAddDiagnosisCode"               

            }, new
            {
                id = "AddStudentDiagnosis-" + @studentId,
                name = "AddStudentDiagnosis-" + @studentId
            }
            ))
        {
```

Functions:

```
function ValidateAddStudentDiagnosisCode(id) {   
    var valid = true;    
    var msg = "";
    var errorPanel = $('#modal-AddStudentDiagnosis-ErrorPanel');
    PopulateErrorMessage(errorPanel, msg);
    errorPanel.hide();
    var diagCode = $('#modal-AddStudentDiagnosis_DiagCode-' + id).val();

    if (diagCode === "") {
        msg = "You must select a diagnosis code";
        valid = false;
    }
    var sequence = $('#modal-AddStudentDiagnosis_Sequence-' + id).val();
    if (sequence === "") {
        msg = "You must select a sequence";
        valid = false;        
    }
    if (valid == false) {
        PopulateErrorMessage(errorPanel, msg);      
    }    
    return valid;
}

function HandleAddDiagnosisCode(e) {

    alert('test');
    var errorPanel = $('#modal-AddStudentDiagnosis-ErrorPanel');
    PopulateErrorMessage(errorPanel, '');
    var errorMessage = e.errorMessage;
    if (errorMessage.length > 0) {
        PopulateErrorPanel(errorPanel, errorMessage);
    }
    else {
        ClearModal();        
        // Reload the document view
        $('#detailPanel').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $(this).empty();
        }).fadeIn(250, function () {
            $(this).html(e.Html);
            BindDocumentEdit();
            BindDataTable();
            BindDatePickers();            
        });
    }
}
```

as I stated above, only ValidateAddStudentDiagnosisCode is running.

Comment: I don't know why your function isn't been called but I can suggest adding an onFailure function. If you do that it might draw out the reason for the issue. Your failure function could be just a console.log()

Comment: Okay that seems like it would be good for extra validation anyways, thanks for the suggestion!